# Hexadecimal colors in ggplot not colored as expected

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

**EDIT:**

I asked a question which boils down to this:

"How can I get ggplot to use hexadecimal colors?"

The answer by MrFick was excellent.

My original question had a terrible typo (read the comments). Instead of deleting this flawed question, I'd recommend just not reading anything below this and then reading the accepted solution. Thanks.

**:END OF EDIT**

I have plotted a few `geom_segment` layers, to make what looks like a vertical bar.

```
p <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[1], xend=value[2]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="green"), size=10)
p <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[2], xend=value[3]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="blue"), size=10)
p <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[3], xend=value[4]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="red"), size=10)
p
```

This gives me:

[image]

For some reason, when I try to replace `red` with `"#CC6666"`, replace `green` with `"#9999CC"`, and replace `blue` with `"#66CC99"`, as such,

```
q <- ggplot()
q <- q + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[1], xend=value[2]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="#66CC99"), size=10)
q <- q + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[2], xend=value[3]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="#9999CC"), size=10)
q <- q + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[3], xend=value[4]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="#CC6666"), size=10)
```

I get:

[image]

Do I somehow need to reset the colors after each plot? And why would I need to do that?

(FFIW, I'm also working in Shiny, where I'm making a set of 6 plots, dynamically. If this is an issue relating to how color is defined in an environment, I might have some extra pain.)

Any help would be appreciated.

The data lives [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hkc3mth9oimlk5/DF_for_plotting.csv?dl=0) and the code is here:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

#DF_for_plotting lives here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hkc3mth9oimlk5/DF_for_plotting.csv?dl=0

p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[1], xend=value[2]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="green"), size=10)
p <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[2], xend=value[3]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="blue"), size=10)
p <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[3], xend=value[4]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="red"), size=10)

q <- ggplot()
q <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[1], xend=value[2]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="#66CC99"), size=10)
q <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[2], xend=value[3]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="#9999CC"), size=10)
q <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[3], xend=value[4]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="#CC6666"), size=10)

grid.arrange(p,q, ncol=2)
```

Comment: There's a typo in your `q` code. you're adding it to `p` which is why you still see the color names.

Comment: ooops! Thanks for the catch! I'll fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to specify a literal color value in a geom_segment, you should not include it in the `aes()`. For example using this test data

```
DF_for_plotting <- data.frame(
    variable=rep("StrpCnCor",4),
    value=c(0, 50.79330935, 81.127731, 100)
)
```

you can do

```
ggplot() +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[1], xend=value[2]-0.001, y=1, yend=1), colour="green", size=10) +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[2], xend=value[3]-0.001, y=1, yend=1), colour="blue", size=10) +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[3], xend=value[4]-0.001, y=1, yend=1), colour="red", size=10)
```

[image]

or with hex colors

```
ggplot() +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[1], xend=value[2]-0.001, y=1, yend=1), colour="#9999CC", size=10) +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[2], xend=value[3]-0.001, y=1, yend=1), colour="#66CC99", size=10) +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[3], xend=value[4]-0.001, y=1, yend=1), colour="#CC6666", size=10)
```

[image]

Although because you're not mapping anything to the color aesthetic, no legend will be provided.

When you put it in the `aes()`, you're not specifying a literal value, you are just specifying a literal value to associate with a color it doesn't matter if you use `aes(color="red")` or `aes(color="determination")`; it just treats it as a literal character value and will use it's own color palate to assign a color to that character value. You can specify your own colors with `scale_fill_manual` For example

```
ggplot() +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[1], xend=value[2]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="a"), , size=10) +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[2], xend=value[3]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="b"), , size=10) +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[3], xend=value[4]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="c"),  size=10) + 
    scale_color_manual(values=c(a="green",b="blue",c="red"))
```

[image]

```
ggplot() +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[1], xend=value[2]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="a"), , size=10) +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[2], xend=value[3]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="b"), , size=10) +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes(x=value[3], xend=value[4]-0.001, y=1, yend=1, colour="c"),  size=10) + 
    scale_color_manual(values=c(a="#9999CC",b="#66CC99",c="#CC6666"))
```

[image]

Here i called the three groups "a", "b", and "c" but you could also call then "green","blue","red" if you want -- it just seems odd to have a legend that tells you what color is green.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer to a flawed question. I'm surprised to see that `color` is not as aesthetic. I need to go read the Grammer of Graphics book and see why it isn't.

Comment: Color is an aesthetic; it just has a different meaning as an aesthetic. The last two plots use `aes(color=)`, that's just not the place where you put the color value.